# move ubuntu hard drive to another laptop

Tags: hard-drive, hp

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed in my HP PAVILION DV6 laptop (office). I want to move the hard disk to my HP PAVILION G6 laptop (personal). I have many software packages installed in my office laptop. Will there be any problem if I do so? I checked many related questions but could not find the one I needed.

I will not be using it in my work laptop anymore. I will switch my personal hard disk and the work hard disk in my personal laptop as i need. How can I achieve this? Is this really possible?

Comment: Ubuntu is usually pretty good with drastic hardware changes. I think the only way to see is to try it. It shouldn't break the install.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I did not try it as i saw may others tried and got stuck at the boot.

Comment: If it does get stuck, putting it back in the old laptop should bring it back to normal.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I just wanted to know what are the procedures that i should follow so i don't get stuck at boot. Any help?

Comment: @Zacharee1 What should i do to not to get stuck at boot and if i dont get stuck will there be any problem if i keep using ubuntu in my personal laptop?

Comment: No, there aren't any. It isn't something that's officially supported by any OS. Ubuntu just happens to have better chances of working.

Comment: It all depends on your computer and exact situation. There's no definitive answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42027/discussion-between-sallu-salman-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work fine and it may crash and burn. There's no real way of telling. Since the two computers are somewhat similar, you may have better luck than others, but there's still no way of knowing. The best you can do is try and see.

If it boots up, that's great. If it doesn't work, your only option is really to manually transfer things over.

Answer (score 1):

I did it several time on desktop PC with no issue at all. Try to move the hdd from one PC to the other. 
Windows is somehow linked to the motherboard of your PC so it make not possible physical migration of an hard drive while with Ubuntu is possible.